# Iphone 4s says i have no storage available

Tags: ios, itunes, iphone, jailbreak

My 6gb iphone 4s says I have no storage left.When I only have 2 apps on this iphone. This iphone was found and it has been jailbroken and erase all content and settings does not work. I've tried it several times but the loading circle never goes away even after I left it for hours. I need help to restore it to factory settings. I do not have access to a laptop so I cannot use iTunes. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "was found" ...was found where? You mean it's not yours?

Answer (score 1):

If erase all content and settings fails to restore the storage then you either have a hardware failure (Flash storage needs to be restored/repartitioned/erased) or a software failure (iTunes is needed to reload the software).

You'll need to take the phone to someone with iTunes and/or experience repairing and testing the iPhone unfortunately.